# Formula writing tool

Tags: math-software

Does someone know any online tool that can allow me to write down mathematical expresions 
such as this one:

[image]

I have lots of this formulas and little exercices, i would like to write down, to be able to add them to a power point presentation. I am not very good with word, so i dont know how to write the above formula in it, so some online tool would be great.

Comment: [TeXRendr](http://texrendr.com/) is an easy-to use tool for LaTeX rendering if that's a viable option for you. For your specific formula enter `\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\cos{|x|} - \cos{|y|}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}` in the field there which you can then retrieve as a `.png`. However, maybe the learning curve for LaTeX might be a bit steep. Most of the tools nowadays are based on [MathJaX](http://mathjax.org).

Comment: Consider solving the original problem by creating your slides with [LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) and its [beamer package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29). It is certainly true that LaTeX needs some getting used to, but in my experience the effort pays off manyfold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - Mathjax does that very thing. It's used here: see the links in the sidebar.

Recent versions of Word do have an equation editor, which allow you to insert stuff into Word documents.

And there are lots of places on the web (including right here), where you can enter an equation with a special type of code (either Latex or MathML), and it will render a beautiful equation, that you can then copy & paste as a graphic.

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\cos{|x|} - \cos{|y|}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

(right-click on that to see the source for it)

Comment: Use this `$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\cos{|x|} - \cos{|y|}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$` for something closer to the picture in the OP: $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\cos{|x|} - \cos{|y|}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Comment: Great tool, i even found the online version that can help me: http://www.kenschutte.com/mathjax Thank you.

Comment: sfrj - you're welcome.  Theo - cheers, that's handy to know